# Proof of causal multicast algorithm?

Tags: dc.distributed-comp

I'm reading [Causal Memory:
Denitions, Implementation and
Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.3356&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and trying to get through the proof of liveliness of the algorithm around the middle of page 9, and I'm not really following it. There's almost certainly a typo/misprint when they refer to the $(s(q) \mathbin\bot 1)$st write. I assume they meant $(s(q) - 1)$st, but even then I'm not really following the reasoning of the proof.

Does anyone have a reference to this proof in the context of a causal multicast that I could look through instead? (or in any other context?)

Alternatively, can someone try to explain the proof. In particular I don't get:

1. "Let $\hat{w}$ be the $(s(q)\mathbin\bot1)$st write." Even assuming $s(q) - 1$, what if $s(q)$ is $0$ or $1$?
2. Why does lemma 1 say that $t(\hat{w}) \preceq t(w)$?
3. Even if we assume $t[j] \ge s[j] - 1$ (equivalently $s[j] \le t[j] + 1$), why is this sufficient? Don't we need to show $s[j] \mathbf{=} t[j] + 1$?

Sorry if this question isn't appropriate/is tagged incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have been mislead by the errors in the proof in the edition of the paper you are referring to. Please refer to the published edition on ["Distributed Computing'1995"](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/601/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01784241.pdf?auth66=1421584284_c32b622096bcfe44327bffb4baf4b47b&ext=.pdf).

> There's almost certainly a typo/misprint when they refer to the $(s[q] \bot 1)$st write.

Yes, it is a typo. It should be "the $(s[i] - 1)$st write" (not $(s[j] - 1)$st either)

> "Let $\hat{w}$ be the $(s[j] - 1)$st write." Even assuming $s[j]−1$, what if $s[j]$ is 0 or 1?

It should be "Let $\hat{w}$ be the $(s[i] - 1)$st write."
By definition, $s$ is the timestamp of the write operation $w$ of process $i$. According to the rule of `Write operation` in Fig.3, we have $s[i] \ge 1$. The problem is what if $s[i] = 1$. Well, it seems that the authors have missed the edge case. Fortunately, it is obviously true that $t[i] = 0 = s[i] - 1$.

> Why does lemma 1 say that $ts(\hat{w}) \le ts(w)$?

$\hat{w}$ and $w$ are two consecutive write operations in process $i$ and $\hat{w}$ is the former one. According to the rule of `Write operation` in Fig.3, we have $ts(\hat{w}) \le ts(w)$. (Actually, we have $ts(\hat{w}) < ts(w)$.)

> Even if we assume $t[i] \ge s[i]−1$, why is this sufficient? Don't we need to show $s[i]=t[i]+1$?

Yes, you are right. That is exactly what are proved in the DC edition.